# Android sipdemo timeout when making calls

Tags: android, sip

Having a problem with the android sipdemo timing out when making calls.  The native sip client on the phone has no issues calling, works perfect.  Its When i initiate the call within the sipdemo i get a timeout in the logcat. timeout is set to standard of 30 seconds.. a local asterisk box is what its connecting to. Registers fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem.
I traced packages in wireshark and here's what I found:

1. I register to SIP server in SipDemo
2. I register to SIP server on Desktop (using Ekiga)
3. I place a call in SipDemo to Ekiga.
4. INVITE message gets sent to Ekiga
5. Trying is sent from Ekiga to the server
6. Ringing is sent from Ekiga to SipDemo
7. I answer the call on Ekiga client
8. OK (with session description) is sent from Ekiga to SipDemo. This happens 11 times before Ekiga just gives up
9. BYE is sent from Ekiga client to SipDemo

Please note that OK is being sent 11 times before Ekiga just gives up and ends the call. This is why the call lasts just 30 seconds.

If you take a look at the RFC here:
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt section 13.3.1.4

you can see that the reason Ekiga is giving up on SipDemo client is because it never gets ACK back from SipDemo.

I believe this is android bug, but I can't imagine they could have missed something this basic in their SIP implementation.

In the next few days, I'll try to dig up some answers in android source code...

I'll try see what happens when establishing calls between 2 SipDemo applications. If it works, that means android just ignores ACK all together.

EDIT:
I just tried a call between 2 SipDemo clients. It sends OK 5 times and gives up on the OK, but does not end the call. Interesting behavior :)

EDIT2:
I dug up androids SIP implementation, and I found that ACK should get sent... Even logcat logs this, but I still see nothing in Wireshark. I thought maybe it gets blocked or something, so I ran Shark (like Wireshark for android) on the device, pulled the dump to my laptop, opened it up in Wireshark, and I don't see ACK anywhere. I even looked trough all packets... No filters, just in case I might be filtering it out. Anyways... Here's what I found in android code:
http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/server/sip/SipSessionGroup.java.html
class: SipSessionImpl
method: private boolean outgoingCall(EventObject evt)
in case Response.OK:
you can see this call:
mSipHelper.sendInviteAck(event, mDialog);

In SipHelper, method sendInviteAck, you can see:
if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "send ACK: " + ack);
dialog.sendAck(ack);

Dialog is nist javax.sip, so I don't think there's a need to go further...
I see this message "send ACK" in my logcat when running the application

EDIT3:
I noticed that this issue occurs only with some SIP servers. I now tried opensips, and it works fine. I guess the problem I was having had to do with the server responding to androids keep-alive OPTIONS messages with 404 Not Found. Then, android tried to not use the server as soon as possible. Because of that, as soon as android got the address of its peer client, it tried to send a direct message, and failed

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell just like that. Try capturing the packages with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), filter for the SIP protocol and have a look at what is sent over the network. Also try it with the native client and compare it to the sipdemo.

Another starting point is the log of your asterisk instance (systemlog)

If you can't figure it out yourself, post the results here.